# find an analytic function satisfies $|f(z)|=e^y/|z|^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

let G be a region in $\mathbb{C}$ with $0 \notin G$; Let $\mathbb{F}$ be the family of all functions $f \in H(G)$ such that for all $z=x+iy\in G$,
$$|f(z)|=e^y/|z|^2$$
Find one function $f_0 \in \mathbb{F}$, and by consideration of $|f(z)|/|f_0(z)|$, where $f$ is any member of $\mathbb{F}$, show that $\mathbb{F}=\{\lambda f_0:\lambda \in \mathbb{C}, |\lambda|=1 \}$.

I am working on this question for a while... My trial is to directly find the $f_0$. Tried several type like $f(z)=e^ycos(x)/(x^2+y^2)+ie^ysin(x)/(x^2+y^2)$..obviously not work. Then I tried $e^{-iz}/|z|^2$ , but realized $|z|^2$ is not differentiable. Maybe replace this $|z|^2$ with other thing? Any hint?

Comment: Why don't you take $e^{-iz}/z^2$ instead?

Comment: yes... thank you!